# Python Key Generator with String dont work

Tags: python, string, random

```
import random


mod1 = "BOT"
mod2 = (random.randrange(1,9999))
mod3 = (random.randrange(1,9999))
mod4 = (random.randrange(1,9999))


key = mod1 + "-" + mod2 + "-" + mod3 + "-" + mod4
print(key)
```

When i run this i become the error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Can anyone Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either convert the mod1-4 to a `String` if you want to concatenate with the character "-" or use `f-string` like below

```
key = str(mod1) + "-" + str(mod2) + "-" + str(mod3) + "-" + str(mod4)

# alternative
key = f"{mod1}-{mod2}-{mod3}-{mod4}"

print(key)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Didn't see your latest edit. I'll delete my answer :)